# UK border inquiry

Tags: uk

Can anybody can advise me what to do? I have been four months visa in the UK and I want to visit Paris for three days for a tour: is it a good idea? Can I still come back to UK after my visit to Paris?

Comment: Is your visa single entry or multiple entry?

Comment: Is leave to remain visa work permitted

Comment: This visa of mind just release to uk immigration  I apply this here in uk, they give me four months only but I can renew it before the expiry, me and my husband plan to visit Paris for three days and come back after, my worry is if  the uk border won’t allow me to entry back in uk because my visa left is four mothns only which that’s the only period they give me in immigration for some reason

Comment: _You have **Limited Leave to Remain** visa in the UK through your spouse with four months validity remaining. You want to visit Paris with your spouse who is the primary beneficiary of the visa_.

Unless you have committed some egregious immigration violation or crime in the UK, or recoursed to public funds which will be discovered at reentry, there is no reason to worry about being denied reentry to the UK. The UK Border force are not in the business of unreasonably separating families.

Comment: Presumably you have a Schengen visa to allow you to go to France?

Comment: Without the full details, it's a bit hard to tell. However, as you were already in the UK, and you were given just an additional 4 months, make sure you are not abandoning an application or pending request by exiting the country. Entry is at the discretion of the border officials and, rather than random strangers on the internet, you may want to [contact the UKVI call centre](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/inside-the-uk/general-immigration-enquiries).

Comment: Thank you for all the advice hight appropriated 